# Magento administration - add maximum allowed price for order creation

Tags: admin, orders, magento-1.6, price-rules

I know that in "Mage_Sales_Helper_Data" class , there is a field "MAXIMUM_AVAILABLE_NUMBER" in order to control maximum allowed number for order price.

I see the functionality in the cart section in frontend.
But I want to have this limit in backend(administration) section. I mean when an admin want to create an order, he shouldn't be allowed to create it if the price is more than a specific amount.

How can I do this?
where should I look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing that i managed to find on the Internet is this article from Inchoo:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/.

It is about setting the frontend limit, so when you define your observer method you will need to place it under the globals tag instead of the frontend tag.